# What causes some icons not to appear when I run my iPhone web app in Safari on the desktop?

Tags: iphone, html, safari, desktop, iphone-web-app

### NOTE: I have rephrased the title because I'm not getting any answers. Surely someone out there has experienced this problem and knows what to do. Thank you!

I have an iPhone web app that works *almost* perfectly in Safari on the desktop. Only two things do not work correctly on the desktop:

1. **Radio buttons** do not appear. They are operational because you can check one if you know where it is; it simply is invisible.
2. When **SELECT** is used, the little box with the default selection in it and the little down arrow do not appear. However, the actual text of the default selection DOES appear. If I click on that text the drop-down menu appears as it should.

In both cases the problem seems to have to do with icons missing or not rendered as needed.

What is the problem and how can I correct it?

Thank you.

Dave

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have any icons missing?  Make sure your paths are correct.

Comment: Do you have an URL for us to check?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your user agent to Mobile Safari?  If you turn on the Develop menu in Safari advanced prefs, you can then test the app in different environments.  It's just a thought.

Comment: Changing the user agent won't affect how the site renders unless there is a different style set up for that user agent.

Comment: The icons that are missing are not part of my app. They are icons that should appear as part of Safari's default behavior. I guess one thing I can do is to create a simple web page that has nothing at all to do with my iPhone web app and see if the icons are still missing.

Comment: Eiko, I cannot provide a URL. The iPhone web app includes a server component that accesses very sensitive customer data.

Lucas, I did try changing the user agent. That did not fix the problem, but thanks for the suggestion.